# How can i store same file from other sources? And what mechanism of storing and naming files in cache?

Tags: flutter

I using CachedNetworkImage (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

My application load and cache image from three sources (they are equal, Depending on the speed connection and availabality). the images are unique.

Ideally i want to put in/get from cache only by filename (it is just a number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CachedNetworkImage widget from the flutter_cache_manager package to load and cache images from a network source, using the image URL as a key for caching. However, if you want to use a custom key for caching, you can use the DefaultCacheManager class from the same package to create a custom cache manager that uses a custom key.